# How to eliminate duplicates in xtext

Tags: xtext

Test:
'Hai' name=ID*;

This is the parser rule.For this can we eliminate duplicates i.e., hai all all.
all is repeating many times .Now is there any way to eliminate duplicates in xtext

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check duplicates in the local file you can adapt and rerun the workflow as follows

```
validator = {
    composedCheck = "org.eclipse.xtext.validation.NamesAreUniqueValidator"
}
```

or write a manual validation (pseudo code, only one of 1000 possible variants)

```
public static val DUP_NAME = 'dupName'

@Check
def checkGreetingStartsWithCapital(Model model) {
    val names = newHashSet
    for (g : model.greetings) {
        if (names.add(g.name)) {
            error("duplicate" , g, MyDslPackage.Literals.GREETING__NAME, DUP_NAME)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it will be applicable to all rules.But I want to apply duplicates check to only one parser rule.Thanks in advance for the solution

Comment: then id recommend to implement a simple check

Comment: Can u please suggest how that simple check can be done

Comment: Thanks a lot Christian

Comment: Can u suggest one more way .Thanks in advance

Comment: Please could provide the xtext for which you have it written the xtend. So that i take reference for mine.

Comment: It's the greeting example created by the wizard

Comment: @ChristianDietrich I have a question similar to this. I will be very thankful if you had the time to look at it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50568506/xtext-validating-for-duplicate-names

Comment: Simply add a check method to your validator