# Xtext - Validating for duplicate names

Tags: validation, xtext, xtend

I have the following grammer, but I want to do some validation on this. I want to make an error if there are duplicate names in the "players" list.

Grammer:

```
Football:
    'Club' name=STRING playerList=PlayerList
     footballObjects+=FootballObject
;

FootballObject:
     Player | Coach
;

PlayerList:
     players+=[Player] ( players+=[Player] )* 
;

Player:
    'Player' name=ID
;
```

I tried the following:

```
@Check
def checkGreetingStartsWithCapital(Football model) {
    val names = newHashSet
    for (g : model.playersList.players) {
        if(!names.add(g.name))
            error("duplicate" , g, FOOTBALLPACKAGE.Literals.FOOTBALL__PLAYERS_LIST)
    }
}
```

But this does not work. Any ideas why?

Comment: shouldn't it be `if(!names.add(g.name))`?

Comment: @lwi you are right. I changed it, but it is still not giving any erros. Could it be something with the Literals?

Comment: I don't see any repetition in your grammar - as far as I can see `players` can't contain more than one element.

Comment: @sepp2k I have updated my question.

Comment: I think it'd be best if you post an actual [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), including the input that you're testing with.

Comment: did you try to add the error to playersList (with index) instead of to the players

Comment: @ChristianDietrich yes, this works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest is to mark the list entry by calling `error` not on the referenced player but on the `playersList` itself and call the `error` method that takes an index as well. e.g.

```
error("bad", playersList, MyDslPackage.Literals.PLAYERS_LIST__PLAYERS, index)
```